# Django - templates no leen archivos en la carpeta "STATIC"

Tags: python, bootstrap, django, django-templates

He probado todas las soluciones que han comentado, pero no logro solucionarlo.

Descargué la plantilla `ONETECH` en `colorlib`. Copié los archivos de `css`, `js` e `img` en el folder `STATIC` ubicado en el mismo directorio que `manage.py`.

Ya hice las configuraciones en `settings.py`, y en el archivo `base.html` *(donde guardo los links y scripts de bootstrap)*.

¿Qué mas puedo intentar?

```
"""
Django settings for ecommerce project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'dj6+vwesy90zg=)4k6&wktb!$om5eqqd9#&otrtv(&7t%e%!(r'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'bootstrap4',
    'shop.apps.ShopConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ecommerce.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ecommerce.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIRS
]


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'products/')

CART_SESSION_ID = 'cart'
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Stack Snippet sólo debe usarse para código ejecutable HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder cargar los archivos estáticos de tu proyecto primero se debe de de crear la carpeta llamada **static** que por lo que ya has comentado, la tienes creada en tu proyecto y debiera de verse algo así (más o menos):

```
  static
   ├───css
   └───js
```

---

Después de ello se deben de agregar dentro del archivo `settings.py` la siguiente línea.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Para hacer referencia de tus archivos estáticos y sepa donde buscar.

---

Por último, se debe de hacer referencia en cada uno de los templates que tengas.

> Que por cierto, *deberías tener en otra carpeta, llamada **templates**
>   y de igual manera se tiene que hacer referencia en `TEMPLATES`*

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Tal que así:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], # para agregar la direccion de tus plantillas HTML
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

---

Dentro de cada plantilla deberás hacer referencia a los arhivos **static**:

```
{load staticfiles}
```

Para hacer que tus archivos static carguen en tu plantilla deberás de llamarlos

Para el CSS

```
<link href="{% static '/css/style.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
```

Para JS

```
 <script src="% static 'js/javascript.js' %"></script>
```

Todo en conjunto quedaría algo así:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Ejemplo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>

    <!-- para hacer referencia a los archivos static -->
    <link href="{% static '/css/style.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />

</head>
<body>


    <!-- para los archivos js -->
    <script src="% static 'js/javascript.js' %"></script>
</body>
</html>
```